# can't set auto_increment mysql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table AAA with two columns: primary key autoincremented ID (int) and a DESCRIPTION (varchar):

```
ID    DESCRIPTION
1     a description
2     a description
3     a description
```

I removed the last entry (ID = 3), and as supposed, when I inserted a new entry the ID was 4.

```
ID    DESCRIPTION
1     a description
2     a description
4     a description
```

Now I removed the ID 4, tryed to set the AUTO_INCREMENT to 3

```
ID    DESCRIPTION
1     a description
2     a description
```

*"ALTER TABLE AAA AUTO_INCREMENT = 3"*

the query said ok but the AUTO_INCREMENT still remain 5. I'm using InnoDB. If there are other thing I missed let me know.

What I have to do to set that auto increment to the very next number 3?

Comment: Why would you want to do this ?

Comment: Your `ALTER TABLE...` should alter your AUTO_INCREMENT to 3. To verify this, after altering use a `SHOW CREATE TABLE aaa;` to verify the AUTO_INCREMENT value after altering. Keep in mind, using this with InnoDB the operation will lead to the DB server rebuilding the entire table. If there is a lot of data in the table, this could take quite a while to complete.

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem, check the following [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9eec3c/1)

Comment: I tryed to change from InnoDB to MyISAM. It worked. I think it's a problem with InnoDB, but I don't know if it's reproducible. I'll give some result after my try.

Comment: I have the same issue as well and from what I've read from a lot of sources whilst googling switching to MyISAM solves the problem, however, I'm bound to Innodb so switching is no option for me. Hopefully someone out there manages to dig something up on why this is happening =/